# iMac late 2015 running Mac os 10.15.4: Connection Logging file is to big to delete

Tags: imac

iMac late 2015 running Mac os 10.15.4: Connection Logging file is to big to delete - not enough storage available. It is 53GB. Available storage is 43GB. I have moved as much user data as possible to external drives. How do I get round this?[image]

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to delete the file you can open a terminal window by launching Applications -> Utilities -> terminal , typing `rm` into the terminal followed by a single space, then drag the file into the terminal window (it should copy the name & full path into terminal) and finally hitting enter.

That location looks like it could possibly require admin privileges to modify files. This would be for a good reason: don't modify any files unless you're completely certain that it's safe to do so. If you do run into access issues, it's possible to proceed by typing `sudo` followed by a space, followed by the line you would have generated in the previous paragraph. Proceed with caution and make sure you have an up to date backup before trying this method.

Comment: Thanks. To try and sort this out, I copied all the non-apple apps from the HD to an external SSD, but not before I checked that it is possible to launch an app directly from the SSD (didn't know this is possible beforehand. Still not enough space. So I deleted Garageband sound stuff and managed to free up enough space to delete the Connection Logging files. Very time consuming. Apple should make it easier to manage this kind of thing.